# How to parse a javascript HTML li object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a object which i looked from firebug looks like following

```
 var object looks like in firebug = [li#demo0 .demo]
```

similarly it can be

```
  [li#demo1 .demo]
```

I am sure demo1 is the id of li and .demo is the class. Now I want to get the id from this object i.e demo1.How can i do this in javascript.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know its always going to have the class of "demo" its nice and easy :) Im assuming your using jQuery (As youve tagged it)

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/HenryGarle/dxbhp/

```
var ulId = $(".demo").attr('id');
alert(ulId);
```

It selects anything with the class of "demo" and then gets the id. If you have multiple elements with the class of demo this would not be suitable but I'm assuming you have not as you've not mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a jQuery object.

```
var obj = $('li#demo1');   // this or some similar selector will produce that object.
```

There are 2 ways you can get the id:

JS:

```
var id = obj[0].id; // or obj.get(0).id
```

jQuery:

```
var id = obj.attr('id');
```